# how to run a function defined in functions.php from frontend

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a function `update_page` defined inside `functions.php` that works perfectly fine when i save post from within the WordPress dashboard.

functions.php

```
function update_page($post_id){
$posttypename =  get_post_type($post_id) ;
$rank=get_field('rank',$post->ID);
update_field('status',$status,$post->ID);
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_page' );
```

the rank gets updated from front end for the post as below. its not full code just a very very short version.

page_ranks.php

```
update_field( 'rank', "2", $post->ID);
```

now i want that the same function `update_page` to run when i make the change to rank from the front end....how do i get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

The simple case scenario is to create a form with a submit.

Upon submission, code should be called to verify that the user was allowed to access that button in the first place, then the function should simply be called and allowed to execute with relevant data.